# What is the figurative meaning of bank shot?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found it used in this sentence - "At least some of these efforts may be intended as an internal bank shot: by sowing doubt externally about the virus’s origins, the CCP can reinforce that view within China without officially promoting it."

Comment: Google [bank shot](https://www.google.com/search?q=bank+shot) for the literal meaning. For the figurative, you need to determine which parts of the description following the colon correspond to which parts of the definition. See also _Cognitive Metaphor_.

Comment: It's a trope for *trope:* that is, for a figure of speech, such as metaphor or praeteritio, designed to indicate a meaning indirectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never heard the term used figuratively before, but it seems the author is referring to an action aimed at a secondary target with the expectation that it will redound to the primary target. In this metaphor, China is the hoop, and the world outside of China is the backboard.

Comment: I had to look up "redound". "rebound" is a more common word.

Comment: Think billiards, not basketball.

Comment: Why does it matter what sport one uses?

Answer (score 0):

In this context, I would say it's the figurative equivalent of [*misdirection*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misdirection), [*indirection*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indirection), or a [*distraction*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distraction).

In colloquial terms, it would be [**sleight of hand**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sleight%20of%20hand):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1 a** : a cleverly executed trick or deception

In other words, regardless of which actual word or term is used, one thing is actually being done even though it appears as if a different thing is being done.

In pool, a bank shot can seem to be taking the cue ball *away* from its final destination at first, only to have it bounce off a rail and actually hit a different target in the final result. But while the cue ball is travelling towards the rail, those who aren't familiar with angles and how pool works might not realize what's going to happen.

This is increasingly true the greater the number of rails that are involved. Somebody watching a cue ball travel in a seemingly random direction, after which it banks off of 5 different rails in turn, might never expect the final result at all.